# Morphisms from quasi-simple regular rigid $\Lambda$-module $M$ to $\tau^m M$ when $\Lambda$ is wild hereditary

Tags: rt.representation-theory, associative-algebras, wild-representation-type

Let $\Lambda$ be a finite dimensional basic wild hereditary algebra and $M$ be an indecomposable regular quasi-simple  right-$\Lambda$ that is rigid in a regular component $\mathcal{R_i}$ of the Auslander-Reiten quiver of $\Lambda$. $k$ is the largest number $l$ such that indecomposables with quasi-length $l$ in $\mathcal{R_i}$ are rigid.

Let $m>0$. Is it true that $Hom(M,\tau^m M)\neq 0$ when $m>k$? I do know that due to [Kerner, 1991](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/002186939190215T) it is true when $m=k+1$. I also know that there exists some $t$ such that when $m>t$ $Hom(M,\tau^m M)\neq 0$ which was proven by Baer and is covered in [Simson-Skowronski, 2006](https://www.amazon.com/gp/search?index=books&linkCode=qs&keywords=9780521882187).